# Can a Bladebound Magus' Black Blade get stronger?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, magus

I am currently playing as a Bladebound Magus and I'm using a Scimitar that has a weapon damage of 1d6. I was curious if that a the Black Blade that the magus gets increases in damage as he levels or all the damage increase will depend on my spells?

I was unable to find something in the book that talks about this, so if there are references please link them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Bladebound Magus entry on d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo---magus-archetypes/bladebound),

The base damage die of the blade doesn't ever increase, but its enhancement bonus does (which affects damage), the number of pool points that power its kewl abilities does (especially Black Blade Strike, which affects damage), and ideally you would take feats that might bump up your damage as you level up.